# Using Paypal IPN for subscription-like purchase

Tags: php, database, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to integrate paypal in a php website but I'm not sure how to use IPN.. or if IPN is the right choice.

In general, for $8 a user can post something for 30 days. After 30 days their posting will expire. For this I will need to insert into the database the date the user made a payment.

Is this possible with IPN? If yes, can someone please share some steps to doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5331883.html

Has some information on it. You may also want to venture over to the http://developer.paypal.com  site and check out the forums / information provided there.